# How to enforce a file to follow a certain signature in typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider having a file named `Controller.ts`.  Is there any way one can force a signature for this file to follow?  For example, the Controller should always export a default value of type `ControllerResponse`. Is there any way for forcing this with typescript?
I already tried putting a `Controller.d.ts` next to it, But it only dictates what "others" see from this file, not how this file should look like itself.
Also, I don't want to touch the containing of the `Controller.ts` file. I basically want to define a "folder and file" schema for the users of my tools that they need to follow and want it to be somewhat automatically enforced.
And I want them to automatically have auto-completes etc. for their files.

Comment: Seeking for an answer myself for this. Did you found something since posting this question @Eddie Cooro?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to achieve this in ts right now.

Comment: Related issues:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38511 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/420 might be a good idea to watch those for more updates